# How can you represent a dependent type visually?

Tags: type-theory, dependent-type, soft-question, programming-languages, formal-languages

So, obviously for a term $t$ of type $T$, I would represent it as:

```
      T
+-----------+
|           |
|     t     |
|           |
+-----------+
```

That is a node labeled $T$ parenting another node labeled $t$.  I'm wondering though how you can represent $\Pi x:A, B(x)$ in a canonical fashion.  MS paint drawings welcome! :)

My attempt and best guess is something like this:

[image: Visualization of a Pi-Type]

So that says that $x$ inhabits the Pi-type $(\Pi_{a:A} B(a))$, hopefully.  So even the labels can be more complicated than a string, i.e. consist of nodes & arrows themselves.  Or is there some better way of doing this?  Your go.

Comment: You'll have to interpret the notion of contexts here

Comment: @ice1000 not sure what you mean, please explain further.

Comment: A context is the thing you wrote at the left-hand side of a judgment. For instance, in $\Gamma \vdash u : A$, the $\Gamma$ is a context. In a DTT, all terms/types are discussed _under a context_.

Comment: @ice1000 isn't the whole current diagram making up the context! :)  I thought a context was like an ordered-AND list of propositions.  In that case empty space is the AND gluing together all the visual expressions inside of it.  If it needs to be ordered, but I'm not sure that it does, you could work with the natural left-to-right top-to-bottom ordering of visual elements.

Comment: Found this: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dependent+type which explains everything categorically, so that's another probably more fruitful approach.  Otoh, you run into a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: Also note that even the expression $f(a)$ expands to a tree rooted with $\cdot (\cdot )$ operator, a left leaf $f$ and right leaf $a$.  In this sense, the whole damn language is a visual graph.  You would search for applicable inference rules using a Luks', Babai's, and Hoffman's group-theoretic algorithms for subgraph isomorphism.  Even though there are nested nodes, you can get away with it by having a special "parent" labeled edge in the graph.

Comment: Your project is an interactive, visual proof explorer? Wherever you're going, it looks fun!

Comment: @DanielMGessel Thank you.  Your comments are a breath of fresh air, positive, and constructive.

Comment: Anyhow, I'm not sure that my approach is very effective.  I'm liking the dictionary between type theory and categorical construcitons as seen on NLab.  And category theory has a natural, visual presentation a lot of times.

Comment: $n$Lab is a great resource! From your post, I would say you are taking a "bottom up" approach. I always end up "eclectic" and include top down design, which is always revealing. In this case, find an interesting and substantial proof then brainstorm out how diagramming the proof might make some aspects clearer. Try using traditional notation at the leaves, see what you can see. Just a thought.

Comment: @DanielMGessel I've taken the top down approach to code many times.  However, I did that with my diagram editors, and then failed at the technical side (the backend / the bottom).  So that's where I'm starting this time.

Comment: Yes - not a purist myself, but periodically look from a purist perspective. This is a meta discussion, but I think it's safe and accurate to say the SE sites are unfriendly toward design discussion (focused on this crowd-sourced Uber FAQ). It's frustrating to find a wealth of knowledgeable people but not be allowed to just as "what do you think?" I haven't found better sites. GItHub offers discussions and a Wiki for each project; if you use GitHub, when you have code to share, enabling discussions and the wiki might be good.

Comment: @DanielMGessel would you like to join me in this visual proof assistant endeavor?  First it would require learning about $n$-groupoid theory, so that we can actually understand what's on NLab.  So first we would just do a study group together.  Great minds think alike!  I am familiary with most basic concepts in Category Theory including Adjoints and Monads.   I would be happy to get you up to speed as a tutor, if you're interested.

Comment: @DanielMGessel The "dictionary" or table I'm referring to on NLab is the second table on this page: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relation+between+type+theory+and+category+theory

As you can see, all but one correspondences are filled in.  I.e. for almost all Type Theory concepts, there exists a categorical (read "visual") interpretation that is well-founded, studied, and rigorous.

Comment: I'll try to figure out if I can absorb anything at a decent rate and ping you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I addressed some of these questions in my lecture “Spartan Type Theory” ([PDF slides](https://math.andrej.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Spartan-Type-Theory.pdf)) at the UniMath 2017 school in Birmingham. In particular, slide 18 looks like this:

[image: A picture of dependent type]

Please look at the slides for further ideas and explanations.

Comment: Thanks! Your timing couldn't be better: I'm about to start my journey toward coming to grips with TT.

Comment: It is an interesting slide presentation, however, this idea seems tangential to what I'm asking, so I cannot select it as the answer.  How would you program a computer using these graphs?  The visual language I presented is much closer to textual type theory than this and so has the potential for being an actual language one could use.  These graphs might be useful in a later version as visualizations for things, but not part of the main language.  For example I don't want to make string-diagram based proofs (a couple of those exist as web apps), I would like something more general than that.

Comment: There is no indication in your question that you are considering graphical programming in dependent type theory, unless you intended to do so with MS Paint.

Comment: I did say that a typed term is represented as an inhabitant of a box node.   And my example preserved that requirement, so… you are clearly smarting me 

Comment: AndrejBauer I'm still absorbing your presentation (a little at a time, like osmosis), but it's given me an excuse to treat myself to a copy of Taschen's (fancy-shmancy) edition of Euclid's Elements. A reprinting of an older attempt to "go graphical" with math, that edition might be (tangentially) relevant to @DanielDonnelly's Q!